# Что бы блоки закрывали один одного, снизу вверх при сужении окна браузера

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть вот такая разметка:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 207px;
  background: green;
}

.centered-middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap-border-center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 280px);
  padding-bottom: 230px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="center">
    <table class="centered-middle">
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td>
          <div class="wrap-border-center">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Когда я потихоньку суживаю окно браузера, то расстояние красного блока между футером и шапкой уменьшается. Потом красный блок упирается в шапку (желтый блок), футер (зеленый блок) начинает налазить сверху красного до тех пор пока не закроет его полностью. Красный блок уже только в конце начинает закрывать желтый блок.

Мне надо, что бы при сужении окна браузера красный начинал закрывать желтый блок еще до того, как его закроет зеленый. Т.е., что бы при очень узком окне браузера на экране отображался красный блок и зеленый, т.к. желтый будет закрыт красным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте медиа-запросы. Например, при высоте меньше 500px, закроем верхний элемент:

```
@media (max-height: 500px) {
    .center {
    ￼    height: calc(100% - 230px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я знал, что нужо поставить условие, но не знал как его реализовать на CSS. Спасибо большое.